# Grafana playlist remove button not seen

Tags: grafana, dashboard, playlist

I have added two test playlists to Grafana and now I can not find the remove button.[image: Grafana Playlist Menu]

I searched [documentations](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/playlist/#delete-a-playlist) and It says there should be a Remove button but I don`t see any.
I am logged in with admin and have full access. What should I do?

Comment: I have the same issue with Grafana 8.1.5. I've created a bug report: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/39929